# Powershell how to create a delegate

Tags: powershell

I am not to familar with powershell. I am trying to do something that would be a single line of code in C# but in powershell it is a pain :(

In the three lines below wow3 throws an error. Anyone know why wow3 throw a type not found error? Does this syntax for delegates only work for built in types?

```
$wow1 =[System.Action[int]]
$wow2 =[MyType]
$wow3 =[System.Action[MyType]]
```

Comment: Where is `MyType` defined?  You likely need to load its assembly, or qualify it with a namespace.

Comment: $wow2 works though. why would wow2 work and not wow3? This is just example, in the actual script I put the full name

Comment: Will a `ScriptBlock` work? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx

Answer (score 45):

This line of PowerShell:

```
$wow1 = [System.Action[int]]
```

is equal to this line of C#:

```
var d = typeof(System.Action<int>);
```

That is, `$wow1` contains a `System.RuntimeType`. Is that really what you are trying to do?

Perhaps you want something like this instead?

```
C:\PS> [Action[int]]$action = {param($i) Write-Host "i is $i"}
C:\PS> $action.Invoke(10)
i is 10
```