# Is there a way to create a Cmdlet "delegate" that supports pipeline parameter binding?

Tags: powershell, delegates, pipeline, scriptblock

In .NET if you have a subroutine whose implementation might change from one call to another, you can pass a delegate to the method that uses the subroutine.  [You can also do this in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849848/powershell-how-to-create-a-delegate).  You can also use scriptblocks which [have been described as Powershell's equivalent of anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351062/1404637).  Idiomatic powershell, however, makes use of powershell's pipeline parameter bindings.  But neither delegates nor scriptblocks seem to make use of Powershell's pipeline parameter bindings.

Is there a (idiomatic) way to pass a powershell commandlet to another commandlet in a way that preserves support for pipeline parameter bindings?

Here is a code snippet of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
Function Get-Square{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x)
    PROCESS{$x*$x}
}
Function Get-Cube{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x)
    PROCESS{$x*$x*$x}
}
Function Get-Result{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x,$Cmdlet)
    PROCESS{$x | $Cmdlet}
}

10 | Get-Result -Cmdlet {Get-Square}
10 | Get-Result -Cmdlet {Get-Cube}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll work.  You've just got some syntax issues with your function definitions and how you're passing the parameters:

```
Function Get-Square{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x)
    $x*$x
}
Function Get-Cube{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x)
    $x*$x*$x
}
Function Get-Result{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$x,$Cmdlet)
    $x | . $cmdlet
}

10 | Get-Result -Cmdlet Get-Square
10 | Get-Result -Cmdlet Get-Cube

100
1000
```

Comment: Interesting.  So `$Cmdlet` is a `[string]`.  And `.` is used to ["dot source"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) the `[string]` and execute it as a script in the context of `Get-Result`.  Is that right?

Comment: Almost right.  It's a function call, rather than a scriptblock invocation.  It's a [string], because function names are [string].

Comment: Hmm...I'm trying to wrap my mind around the implications of "It's a function call".  I also determined that I actually also need to pass named and positional parameters with the cmdlet being passed.  It's related but doesn't really fit into this question so [I asked it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28486411/1404637).

Comment: About the only implication is what kind of parameter you pass.  Because it's a named function, you can just pass the name.  If it was an "unnamed" or anonymous function, you'd need to pass the script block.

Comment: This all makes sense now.  Thanks for your help.  :)