# How to replace with evaluated code in powershell?

Tags: regex, perl, powershell

I'm having some difficulty finding a "native" powershell -replace call that would replace a match with something based on the match.  E.g. in perl it would be like this:

```perl
my %definedVars = ( ab => "hello", cd => "there" );
my $str = q"$(ab) $(cd)";
$str =~ s/\$\(([^)]+)\)/$definedVars{$1}/ge;
print "$str\n";
```

I was thinking that in powershell, it'd be something like this:

```powershell
$definedVars = @{ ab = 'hello'; cd = 'there' }
'$(ab) $(cd)' -replace "\$\(([^)]+)\)", { $definedVars[$1] }
```

I've looked around and I think that the `-replace` switch doesn't have an deferred evaluator, so I'd have to use the .NET `replace` function, but I'm not entirely sure how that works.  I'm thinking it would be something like this:

```powershell
$definedVars = @{ ab = 'hello'; cd = 'there' }
[regex]::replace('$(ab) $(cd)',
   "\$\(([^)]+)\)",
   { $definedVars[$_.Groups[1].Value] } )
```

Documentation is sparse, so if you could also state where you got your info from, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is just a syntax problem.  I have to specify the parameter and use that.  `$_` is not defined as a special default parameter.  So it would be like this:

```powershell
$definedVars = @{ ab = 'hello'; cd = 'there' }
[regex]::replace('$(ab) $(cd)',
   "\$\(([^)]+)\)",
   { param($m); $definedVars[$m.Groups[1].Value] } )
```

## Edit

As mjolinor pointed out, instead of defining the params, I could use `$args` array instead, like this:

```powershell
$definedVars = @{ ab = 'hello'; cd = 'there' }
[regex]::replace('$(ab) $(cd)',
   "\$\(([^)]+)\)",
   { $definedVars[$args[0].Groups[1].Value] } )
```

This is slightly better if I'm only referencing that parameter once, but if the delegate gets more complex, IMO it would still be better to use `param` to specify the parameters.

Comment: This is correct; you have to define a parameter for the script block and use that to receive each match.

Comment: I got the syntax from [Powershell how to create a delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850707/1366368).

Comment: You don't have to define the parameter.  You can use $args -> [regex]::replace('$(ab) $(cd)',
   "\$\(([^)]+)\)",
   { $definedVars[$args[0].Groups[1].Value] } )

Comment: It would have been nice if the native `-replace` had a evaluation syntax.

Comment: @mjolinor, I had tried `$args` before and couldn't get it working.  Thanks for the reminder.