# [Generic.List].ForEach() method in PowerShell, how to reference the passed item

Tags: powershell, foreach

Given a simple generic list of strings like this

```
$log = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
$log.Add('?_Label')
$log.Add('=_Item')
```

I can replace prefixes with something like this

```
$log | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^\?_', 'E_'}
```

But I would like to understand how to do this with the `.ForEach()` method rather than the pipeline.
I have tried

```
$log.ForEach({$_ -replace '^\?_', 'E_' })
$log.ForEach({$arg -replace '^\?_', 'E_' })
$log.ForEach({param([String] $item) $item -replace '^\?_', 'E_' })
```

and none works.
I know from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-foreach(system-action((-0)))) that I need a delegate, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0) in theory should tell me how to do it. But I am at a loss.
I also found [this](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/12/10/foreach-method-in-powershell.aspx) which is what sent me down the initial rabbit hole, but this is obviously a native PowerShell `.ForEach()` method, where `$_` is valid, and I am dealing with a native .NET method, where `$_` does not apply. But I think there is even more that I am missing.

Comment: The one with `param (...)` should work (or just using `$args[0]`), but keep in mind that the ForEach method is only for side effects; it doesn't return anything.

Comment: `List<T>` `.ForEach` method is not the same as the intrinsic `.ForEach` method

Comment: @jkiiski Ugh. I could have sworn there was a way to return something too.

Comment: You might simply do: `$log -replace '^\?_', 'E_'`

Comment: @iRon, that does the trick. I just need to cast back to List and I am off to the races. `$log = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]($log -replace '^\?_', 'E_')`

Answer (score 1):

You can [create new delegate using `[System.Action[type]]$actionName` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849848/powershell-how-to-create-a-delegate)

```
[System.Action[String]]$action = {param($item) Write-Host ($item -replace '\?_', 'E_') }
```

and pass this Action `$action` to `ForEach` method.

```
$log.ForEach($action)
```

Comment: Hey, I have an off topic question. Would this apply to the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32364847/14903754)? Seeing as `[System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel]::ForEach()` doesn't know about runspaces?